# pixel access in opencv when using GPU (CUDA)

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, cuda, gpu

How can I access pixels of image in opencv if I want use GPU?
is there something GPU specific? for example speed of access and so on?
can it be simpler through opencv's interface then through plain CUDA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access it the same way you access it on the CPU (it's just a block of memory stored in IplImage data field). Accessing the pixels faster really depends on the algorithm you wish to implement, for instance if you want to run a convolution than using the GPU shared memory will assist you.
You may want to consider placing the Image in the texture memory. It could help boost performance when accessing pixels.